# CatBoostClassifier after upgrade to 0.21 version grid-search error out

Tags: catboost

I tried to upgrade my catboost to latest version which is now 0.21 which is causing issue from code.

What is the alternative or any method while upgrading this:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(loss_function='MultiClass',
                           eval_metric='MultiClass',
                           custom_metric=['F1'],
                           class_weights=class_weights,
                           random_seed=42)

grid = {
        'learning_rate': [0.03, 0.09, 0.1,0.01],
        'depth': [5,7,10],
        'iterations': [300, 250,280,400],
        'colsample_bylevel':[1,2,4,5],
        'l2_leaf_reg': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
       }

randomized_search_result = model.grid_search(grid,
                                                   cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5),
                                                   X=train_x_full, 
                                                   y=train_y_full,
                                                   refit=True, 
                                                   shuffle=True, 
                                                   stratified=True,
                                                   plot=True)
```

Error is as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-771fe8b0efaa> in <module>
     14        }
     15 
---> 16 randomized_search_result = model.grid_search(grid,
     17                                                    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5),
     18                                                    X=train_x_full,

AttributeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object has no attribute 'grid_search'
```

Comment: If i Downgrade the version to 0.20.2 then below error i found:

```CatBoostError: util/generic/hash.h:1668: Key not found in hashtable: F1:class=0```